# links in bootstrap menu doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying make a navigation menu following the [bootsrap API](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

Here is what I have:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="Home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Login" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="Prediction" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Predict</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to redirect to different urls by pressing these tabs. 
The problem is that links doesn't work in menu context and DO work if I just write:

```
<a href="Home">Home</a>
<a href="Login">Login</a>
<a href="Prediction">Predict</a>
```

The problems appear when I add `role="tab" data-toggle="tab"` to a menu element.
If I will remove `role="tab" data-toggle="tab"` then it stops to behave like tabs (no active tab).

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you referencing the relevant bootstrap js/css files?

Comment: @Andrew Matthew, I got it 2 hours ago with NUGET package(Bootstrap v3.0.1). So I think it's quite relevant :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to toogle different div's based on the link you click on.
You need to reference the target element using `#target` in each `href=`, where `target` is the `id` of the element you want to open.

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enUS7/1/).

If that's not what you are looking for then please be a bit more specific of what you are trying to accomplish.

**Update based on comment:** just remove `data-toogle="tab"` from the links and replace `href="#home"` with `href="/home"` or whatever path you want to navigate to.

Comment: I want to use menu for navigation(to a specific url) and not for displaying different text.

Comment: I did try that already. If I remove data-toogle="tab" it would not work as tabs. I do want it to look like bootstrap tabs that you can click and not just like usual links.

Comment: You would then need to add `class="active"` to the parent `li` element based on which link you clicked. Say you are on `/home` and click the `/login` link, you would then need to remove `class="active"` from `a href="/home"`'s  parent `li` element and add it on `a href="/login"`'s parent `li`. See [this](http://snipplr.com/view/41829/nav-with-classactive-based-on-page/) for an example.

Comment: I did, the problem that if I click on another tab, the same "active" tab remains active without data-toogle="tab" attribute. The only solution I found is to do it by hand in js code: $('#menu1')[0].className = "active"; but it's very ugly

Comment: The typical way of doing this is in php or any other language on the server side, like the example in my previous comment. However, without knowing your setup the only thing I can suggest is to search further. If you want to handle this in javascript you would need to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20060541/536287).